# How can I access the current node from a library in a Chef cookbook?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm attempting to write a library for a chef cookbook that simplifies some common searches.

For example, I'd like to be able to do something like this in `cookbook/libraries/library.rb` and then use it from a recipe in the same cookbook:

```
module Example
    def self.search_attribute(attribute_name)
        return search(:nodes, node[attribute_name])
    end
end
```

The problem is that, inside a Chef library file neither the `node` object or `search` function are available.

Search seems to be possible by using `Chef::Search::Query.new().search(...)`, but I can't find anything that works to access `node`. The resulting error from this is:

```
undefined local variable or method `node' for Example:Module
```

Using Chef 10.16.4.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081109/1626687

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is to include the module in your recipe. That way, your module functions get access to the methods of the recipe, including `node`.

I normally do this for my library modules:

```
# my_cookbook/libraries/helpers.rb
module MyCookbook
  module Helpers
    def foo
      node["foo"]
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in the recipe, I include the module into the current instance of a recipe:

```
# my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb
extend MyCookbook::Helpers
```

That way, only the current recipe gets the module included, not all of them in the whole chef run (you thus avoid name clashes).

Alternatively, you could pass the current node as a parameter to the function. That way, you don't need to include the module (which has the upside of keeping the module namespaces) but has the downside of a more convoluted method call.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but what do you mean by "That way, only the current recipe gets the module included, not all of them in the whole chef run"?

Comment: People often call `Chef::Recipe.include MyCookbook::Helpers` which makes the helper functions available in all recipes (and can overwrite potentially already existing ones with the same name). I think this is a code smell and prefer my version to only include the `Helpers` module into a recipe explicitly.

Comment: I think I understand. Using Ruby's extend would only add the methods from the module to the single recipe object that's running, whereas using include like you mentioned would add it to all Chef::Recipe objects. Thanks!

Comment: for me, `extend MyCookbook::Helpers` still doesn't allow access to node attributes...

Comment: @s2t2 Please ask a new question, detailing what you tried (including your recipe and library code) and what exactly went wrong. You can link to this answer from your new question to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this while trying to access the current environment in a library. I couldn't really figure out how to use modules to get access to the node and I didn't want to pass the node into each method call (or the instantiation call) so I did this (example code.. not the actual functionality):

```
# libraries/account.rb
class Account
  @@env = "_default"

  def self.env=(env)
    @@env = env
  end

  def settings
    Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load(@@env, "settings") || {}
  end
end

# recipes/accounts.rb
Account.env = node.chef_environment

Account.new.settings
```

I don't know if using class variables is frowned upon, but it works in all my tests and it's nice and easy to use.