# Access Node attributes in Chef Library

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'd like to create a Chef library that:

- Provides a few namespaced functions
- Accesses the node's attributes

That library is meant to interface with an external system and retrieve some inputs from there. I need to access the node attributes to allow the user to override the inputs received from the external system:

### Desired Usage (Recipe)

```
inputs = MyLib.get_inputs
```

### Library (What I have now)

This is inspired by [those docs](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_libraries.html).

```
class Chef::Recipe::MyLib
  def self.get_inputs
    override_inputs = node.fetch(:mylib, Hash.new).fetch(:override_inputs, nil)

    unless override_inputs.nil?
      return override_inputs
    end

    # Do stuff and return inputs (no problem here)
    # ...
  end
end
```

### Problem

Right now I'm getting:

```
undefined local variable or method `node' for Chef::Recipe::Scalr:Class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access the current node from a library in a Chef cookbook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134728/how-can-i-access-the-current-node-from-a-library-in-a-chef-cookbook)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't have access to the node object in a library unless you pass it into the initializer:

```
class MyHelper
  def self.get_inputs_for(node)
    # Your code will work fine
  end
end
```

Then you call it with:

```
inputs = MyHelper.get_inputs_for(node)
```

Alternative, you can to create a module and mix it into the Chef Recipe DSL:

```
module MyHelper
  def get_inputs
    # Same code, but you'll get "node" since this is a mixin
  end
end

Chef::Recipe.send(:include, MyHelper)
```

Then you have access to the `get_inputs` method right in a recipe:

```
inputs = get_inputs
```

Notice this is an **instance method** versus a class method.

In short, libraries don't have access to the `node` object unless given as a parameter. Modules will, if they are mixed into the Recipe DSL. Additionally, the `node` object is actually an **instance variable**, so it's not available at the class level (i.e. `self.`).

Comment: "since they are mixed into the Recipe DSL". Would maybe be more correct say they have access _if_ they are mixed in to the Recipe module.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a scoping issue here as the Node's scope is under Chef::Recipe. So try omitting MyLib in the definition and see if it works. I have a library defined this way that works:

```
class Chef
  class Recipe
    def my_library_method
      #access node stuff here should be fine
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Omitting the lib declaration would mean that `get_inputs` ends up in the global namespace for recipes that depend on my cookbook, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, this is why it is generally better practice to keep the bulk of your code in a helper module and pass in the node object.

Comment: This is actually a very bad practice known as "Monkey patching". You should never re-open a class like this in Ruby. Instead, extend it using a module. It preserves the inheritance and lookup chains.

Comment: Because `Chef::Recipe` is a class instead of a module, it cannot be extended, right?

Comment: oh, maybe you `extend MyModule` from the default recipe? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19135015/670433 but it can't access the node attributes...