# Determining the Operating System in a Chef Library

Tags: chef-infra

There is no access to `os.windows?` in a chef library, whereas in a recipe it is available. I thought it might be possible to get it by adding a `require 'os'` line to my library to make it available.

```
require 'os'

module Project
  module Helper
    # ...
    def serviceExists?(service_name)
      if os.windows?
        puts 'Windows detected'
        # ... etc ...
      else
        raise 'Unimplemented..'
      end
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

This didn't work. Instead I received an error:

```
LoadError
---------
cannot load such file -- os
```

Is it possible to access the `os` variable or determine the operating system in a library without passing `os` as a parameter to the method? I was hoping to handle the os complexities in the library to keep the recipe cleaner.

I'm calling the code via the following `not_if` statement.

```
batch "Install #{service_name} service" do
  extend Project::Helper
  cwd install_home
  code <<-EOH
    @echo off
    call \"installSvc.cmd\"
  EOH
  not_if { serviceExists?(service_name) }
end
```

Comment: I thought about doing something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/20341462/1247302, but it feels dirty.

Comment: Tried mixing the module into the Recipe DSL via `Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Project::Helper)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/22081109/1247302, but I got errors that `os` doesn't exist as a method. `undefined method `os' for Chef::Resource::Batch` (i'm calling from a `not_if` in the recipe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed approach slightly instead of trying to access the `os` object directly, I instead used the `node` object via a 'mixin'.

```
require 'win32/service'

module Project
  module Helper
    def serviceExists?(service_name)
      if node['os'].include?('windows')
        Win32::Service.exists?(service_name)
      else 
        raise 'Checking for services under this platform is not implemented yet.'
      end
    end
  end
end

Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Project::Helper)
Chef::Resource.send(:include, Project::Helper)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`ohai`](https://github.com/chef/ohai)...

install it using [`gem_package`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_gem_package.html) resource and then leverage ohai:

```
require 'ohai'
ohai = Ohai::System.new
ohai.all_plugins
os = ohai[:kernel][:os].downcase
```