# How to use Chef "search" method in library code (in module method)?

Tags: chef-infra

I encountered a problem about using "search" method in library code:
libraries/helpers.rb

```
Bcpc
  Helper
    extend self
    def help(node=node)
      search(:node, "....")
    end
  end
end
Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Bcpc::Helper)
```

Chef::Resource.send(:include, Bcpc::Helper) for the recipes using module methods.

Then use this module method in recipes like this:
Bcpc::Helper.help(node)
When I run it, it report the error that search method is not defined in Bcpc::Helper:Module

I found the search method is defined in Chef::Search::Query class. Then I tried use the full name of search in my library code like: Chef::Search::Query.search(:node, "....").
But it reported search is undefined in Chef::Search::Query. 
Should this search method be a static method that can be called with its class name?

How can I use the Chef provided "search" method in my library code in this case?
Thanks!

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134728/how-can-i-access-the-current-node-from-a-library-in-a-chef-cookbook, it seems to be simmilar question as yours.

Comment: @rastasheep ThANKS, Yah, similar. But here it is a method. I also think to pass in the method reference in parameter. But I want to see other better ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want something like this.

```
Chef::Search::Query.new.search(:node, 'foo:bar') do |n|
  # something with n
end
```

Comment: Thank your for your solution, it really helpful. Here I have a concern. Is the "Chef::Search::Query.new.search(:node, 'foo:bar')" return the same as search(:node, 'foo:bar')? I think this "search" function runs against Chef Server. So maybe the context for "search" is constructed during chef runs. But if we use "Chef::Search::Query.new.search(:node, 'foo:bar')", does it still can aware of the context. Anyway, I will give it a try, and report my results.

Comment: Yes, just look at the implementation of the [`search()` helper](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/dsl/data_query.rb#L34-L47)